# Getting next sequence value in correct order

Tags: oracle, jdbc, pyspark

I have a function in oracle database that gets me the next value of the sequence. I also have a following PySpark Code:

```
def get_next_seq_value():
    QUERY = "SELECT SCHEMA.GET_NEXT_SEQ_VALUE FROM DUAL"
    sqlContext.clearCache()
    next_seq_value_df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url=URL, driver=DRIVER, QUERY=QUERY, user=USER, password=PASSWORD).load().unpersist()
    next_seq_value = next_seq_value_df.take(1)[0][0]
    return next_seq_value
```

And I call this function from here:

```
array = []
for each_item in df_list:
    next_seq_value = get_next_seq_value().encode('utf-8').strip()
    array.append(next_seq_value)
```

The problem is the following:

When I run the following the array looks like this:

['545671', '545672', '545673', '545694', '545695', '545696']

Why don't I see the 545674 and 545675... it just skipped to '545694'. How do I make sure it calls the function in order.

Comment: What is your sequence definition? Docs: "[Specify NOORDER if you do not want to guarantee sequence numbers are generated in order of request. **This is the default**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571)"

Answer (score 2):

[Default sequence cache size](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571) is 20:

> If you omit both CACHE and NOCACHE, then the database caches 20 sequence numbers by default.

So looks like another session called `nextval` of your sequence between your calls.

In addition from your code `QUERY = "SELECT SCHEMA.GET_NEXT_SEQ_VALUE FROM DUAL"` looks like you wrapped `your_sequence.nextval` into the function `GET_NEXT_SEQ_VALUE`. It looks like overkill here: you get extra calls (SQL->PL/SQL-> call `.nextval()`) and overhead here. You can either use just `select seq.nextval from dual` or `:x := seq.nextval;`. And if you want to generate N values, you can use: `select seq.nextval from dual connect by level<=20;`

Comment: What if you use: select seq.nextval from dual connect by level <= n where n is the number of sequence numbers you want. In this case, you don't have to use a foreach loop to get sequence one at a time. If n = length of the df_list then you only call the query once, will it be in order as long as the n > 20 (cache size)

Comment: Also, how would you convert this function to use connect by:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NEXT_SEQ_NUM RETURN NUMBER IS
  SEQ_TEMP NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SEQ_TEMP := SCHEMA.SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  RETURN SEQ_TEMP;
END GET_NEXT_SEQ_NUM;
/

Comment: "will it be in order as long as the n > 20 (cache size)" - obviously it will be in ascending order.

Comment: @kpatel23 "how would you convert this function to use connect by" - you can create another function that returns a collection of number (`create type number_table as table of number` + `create function ... return number_table` + `select x.nextval bulk collect into res...` + `return res;`)

Comment: pyspark doesn't support return of array's so it wouldn't work. Is there a way after you get collection you convert it to rows?

Comment: @kpatel23 why do you need a  function for this? Why not just suggested `select seq.nextval from dual connect by level<=:n`?

Comment: and of course, you can use either pipelined functions (`return varchar2_table pipelined`) or just wrap a function that returns collection into `select * from table(your_function)`

Comment: "pyspark doesn't support return of array's " - are you sure? have you tried to execute `select sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3) from dual`?

Comment: I tried select * from table(your_function) and it worked perfectly!!. Just few questions, does the connect by level <= x scale nicely (let's say x = 100000) also does the collection have max element limit (if x = 100000, then collection will also be 100000)

Comment: In this case I would suggest without sql in the query, just use `for I IN 1..N loop pipe row (seq.nextval); end loop;`

Comment: I have the following, I think it can be scalable because associative array can support unspecified amount of elements, so collection list can grow large. My only question is does connect by level support large numbers. Here is my code:

Comment: CREATE OR replace type SEQ_ASSOCIATIVE_ARRAY is table of VARCHAR2(32);
/
show error

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NEXT_SEQ_LIST(i_quantity IN INTEGER) RETURN SEQ_ASSOCIATIVE_ARRAY IS seq_list SEQ_ASSOCIATIVE_ARRAY;
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT TO_CHAR(SEQ.NEXTVAL) FROM SYS.DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ' || TO_CHAR(i_quantity) BULK COLLECT INTO seq_list;
RETURN seq_list;
END GET_NEXT_SEQ_LIST;
/
show error

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is *apparently* not the **wrong order** of the *sequence generated `ID`s but the **gaps**.

While you decide to use sequences you generally **must count with gaps**.

If you use the default cache size of 20 you will loose on average with end of each *session* 10 `ID`s.

You may reduce this with `NOCACHE` but even here is you call the `nextval`and than rollback the transaction this ID may gets lost. As the next transaction typically starts with a new `nextval`...

Comment: Sequences are cached for sessions, not transactions, so in case of just one session (without disconnects and other sessions calling this sequence) calling a sequence, there will not be any gaps, it doesn't matter how many commits you called

Comment: You are of course right @SayanMalakshinov sorry for my *wrong* formulation.

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree with both of the previous answers. I'm not sure what type of database architecture you're using, but I'd also like to point out that with Oracle RAC each cluster node instance will have a separate cache for the sequence too.

Eg:

```
node 1: sequence cache 101-120
node 2: sequence cache 121-140
node 3: sequence cache 141-160
```

So depending on which node happens to process a request the nextval might not be in sequential order, either.

The point is that when using sequences you should only count on the values being *unique*, not necessarily without gaps (eliminating the cache can impact performance severely), or even necessarily in sequential order depending on your physical server architecture. If keeping things in sequential order no matter what is important, add a timestamp to your record in addition to the sequence counter.